# Plot grouped bar plot for each subcategory within top 2 categories using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, bar-chart

I have a dataset very similar to sample dataset given below:

```
| Category | SubCategory | id | State | Population |
|----------|-------------|----|-------|------------|
| A        | chair       | 1  | CA    | 100        |
| A        | desk        | 2  | CA    | 150        |
| A        | chair       | 3  | NY    | 80         |
| E        | fan         | 4  | AZ    | 60         |
| E        | ac          | 5  | PA    | 55         |
| B        | chair       | 6  | PA    | 78         |
| E        | fan         | 7  | PA    | 90         |
| B        | table       | 8  | PA    | 120        |
| A        | bed         | 9  | UT    | 105        |
| A        | chair       | 10 | NY    | 156        |
| A        | desk        | 11 | NY    | 99         |
```

Below is the dataframe:

```
category= c("A","A","A","E","E","B","E","B","A","A","A")
subcategory = c("chair","desk","chair","fan","ac","chair","fan","table","bed","chair","desk")
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
population = c(100,150,80,60,55,78,90,120,105,156,99)
df= data.frame(category, subcategory, id, population, stringsAsFactors = T)
```

If we look at the table, the total count of column 'id' for each category A, B and E are 6,2,3 (Basically, the occurrence of each category). Now, I have been wanting to plot a grouped bar plot using ggplot2 for each subcategory belonging to top 2 category (Top 2 is determined by the count of column 'id'). So, my output should show only categories A and E and the count of column id should be plotted against y axis belonging to each subcategory (As shown below):
[image]

My block of code is giving me top 2 subcategories based on count of id for each category, whereas, I'm looking to plot all the subcategories based on count of id for top 2 categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>% add_count(category, name = 'rank') %>%
  filter(dense_rank(desc(rank)) %in% 1:2) %>%
  count(category, subcategory) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = n, fill = subcategory)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge(1), vjust = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add the data label at top of each bar. With my piece of code, the values are aligning in a straight line. ```  geom_text(aes(x=category, y=n, label=n),size = 3, colour="black", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))```

Comment: I meant to display the id count of each subcategory and not the subcategories, for example, the first bar would have '1' as text at top the bar, 2nd bar would have '3' as text and so on. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: but your chart in question mean something like this.  Nevetheless `label = n` should do the job